# VSCode regexp searching cannot match the CR (\r) character

Tags: visual-studio-code, line-endings

I want to search and replace all the `CRLF` into `LF` line endings. So in VSCode I search regexp `\r`. But there is no result.

As compared, I search `\n` and I got all the line endings highlighted.

I use linux command `xxd` to check the file and I'm sure there is a `CR` character in this file.

---

An example is shown below:

[image: search result of LF]

[image: search result of CR]

As shown in these screenshots, searching `\n` gives one result but searching `\r` gives no result. The bottom terminal shows that the file contains three bytes: `0x61`(char `a`), `0x0d`(control char `CR` or `\r`), and `0x0a`(control char `LF` or `\n`)

The file `test.txt` is uploaded here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JGx_TU-7JSJ93tKxXycfFscqPEHENUjz

---

Environment:

VSCode Information:

```
1.36.1
Commit: 2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529
Date: 2019-07-08T22:59:35.033Z
Electron: 4.2.5
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
```

The `code` and `xxd` commands are provided by WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Comment: `\r` is `CR`, `\n` is `LF`

Comment: Oh thanks! I have corrected it.